# Which Auth Provider to Employ when using Confidential Client Application .net 7

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, migration, .net-7.0

I am migrating and older app to .net 7 and updating the libraries along the way. I am having one heck of a time figuring out the changes to MSGraph v5.

Googling I found a number of suggestions that I have not been able to work. In my Startup.cs file, I have this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

public static class GraphConfiguration
{ 
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureGraphComponent(
        this IServiceCollection services, 
        IConfiguration configuration
    )
    {
        var graphConfig = configuration.GetSection("AzureAD");
        var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(graphConfig["ClientId"])
            .WithTenantId(graphConfig["Tenant"])
            .WithClientSecret(graphConfig["ClientSecret"])
            .Build();

        var authenticationProvider = new ??????(confidentialClientApplication);

        // Use a single client instance for the lifetime of the application
        services.AddSingleton(sp => new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider));

        return services;
    }
}
```

I gave the Delegate auth provide a try but it seems like it is no longer avaiable. Any idea which Auth provider I can use? In the code above, I am looking to fix the following line:

```
var authenticationProvider = new ??????(confidentialClientApplication);
```

Thanks, E.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `ClientSecretCredential` class from `Azure.Identity` NuGet.

```
var clientSecretCredentials = new ClientSecretCredential(graphConfig["Tenant"], graphConfig["ClientId"], graphConfig["ClientSecret"]);
services.AddSingleton(sp => new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredentials));
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting ` Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient' while attempting to activate FooController` . Using `private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;` then using `public FooController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)`

Answer (score 0):

when we use `MSGraph v5`, then the `GraphServiceClient` are available for these 4 construction methods. And like you can see we only have this method which allows `authenticationProvider`.

```
public GraphServiceClient(IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, string baseUrl = null)
    : this((IRequestAdapter)new BaseGraphRequestAdapter(authenticationProvider, graphClientOptions), baseUrl)
{
}
```

[image]

Then let's see the [upgrade guidance](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#authentication) here.

> In place of the DelegateAuthenticationProvider, custom authentication
> flows can be done creating an implementation of IAccessTokenProvider,
> and using with the BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider from the
> Kiota abstractions as follows

We need to implement token provider to use `BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider`, and I have a test with code below and it really worked but I don't think it matches your requirement..

```
StringValues authorizationToken;
HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authorizationToken);
string incomingToken = authorizationToken.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
TokenProvider provider = new TokenProvider();
provider.token = incomingToken;
var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(provider);
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
var user = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();

public class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object>? additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(token);
    }
}
```

So my idea is that, if you want to get a auth provider to use, then `BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider` is the only option for you according to the guidance. If `AuthorizationCodeCredential` is an option for you, then you might refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp) to find the suitable one. Or you might to use  `MSGraph v4` instead of v5 to continue to use `DelegateAuthenticationProvider`.